# How to notify Admin by any kind of notification that the task's status change , reached deadline and task finishes in odoo automatically

Tags: python, html, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I am a starter in odoo. Can anyone help me to find a solution for the problem mentioned below?

Consider I am an Admin of the Odoo ERP, I needs to be noticed automatically about the status change of task , dead line reached , task finishes kind of informations as a message or notification pop up.

Expected Goal  : The admin will creates the projects and some tasks inside the projects. Those tasks will be assigned to the employees. The employees will be adding their work on the specific tasks assigned to particular employee. Hence the goal we want is to let the admin knows about the tasks status if that task reaches the deadline automatically by notification. Also admin should notice about the stage change of the tasks.

Can anyone help me to achieve this goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: Updated my expected result. Expecting reply from your end.. thanks

Comment: With task you mean a entry in *project.task* model? Right?

Comment: yes.. you are correct..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I expect a basic knowledge about how to write a module for odoo.

**First step**
Add an email template, that will be send to the admin. You can do it by adding the */your_module_name/data/data.xml* file to your module. And fill it with the following code.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <openerp>
      <data>
         <record id="mail_to_admin_when_task_changed" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">Notification for admin</field>
            <field name="email_from">${object.user_id.login}</field>
            <field name="subject">Task state changed</field>
            <field name="email_to">admin@maildomain.com</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_task"/>
            <field name="lang">${object.user_id.lang}</field>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
                Hello admin, the new state for <b>${object.name}</b> is <b>${object.state}</b>.
            ]]></field>
          </record>
      </data>
  </openerp>
```

Regist your *data.xml* file to your `__openerp__.py` by adding the path to the data-list.

```
# ...other openerp definition
'data': [
        'data/data.xml'
        #...paths to views
    ],
# ...other openerp definition
```

**Second step**
Overwrite the `write()` method in `project.task`model. You can do it by inherit the `project.task` model.
Create a `project_task.py` in your *models* folder. Regist it to your `__init__.py`. Then write the following code to `project_task.py`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models, fields, api, osv

class project_task(models.Model):
    _inherit = "project.task"

    def write(self,cr,uid,ids,vals,context=None):
        mtp = self.pool.get('email.template')
        mail_to_admin_template_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'your_module_name', 'mail_to_admin_when_task_changed')[1]

        if "state" in vals:
           for id in ids:
               mtp.send_mail(cr,uid,mail_to_admin_template_id,id,force_send=True,context=context)


        return super(project_task,self).write(cr,uid,ids,vals,context=context)
```

Please let me know if there is something to edit.

Comment: That is one possiblity, yet another is to use Odoo's internal mail system with some custom modfifications.

Comment: @CZoellner Maybe your solution is easier to understand. Can you explain it in an answer. I would probably vote your answer up.

Comment: Actually i don't think the other solution is easier to understand. And there is no official doc (on the current docs) for that, too. It's just using the model `mail.thread` and all its functionality: chatter, followers, triggered mails, notes, etc. pp.